# Python comparing three lists with different lengths

Tags: python, list, compare

I am trying to compare three different lists each with a potentially different length to the others but I'm not exactly sure how to do this. Originally I thought to just get the largest list length but then realized if the others are less then it will try find empty elements and return an error.
I am trying to find if all the lists have a common element

Currently I have:

```
for i in range(n) //n is largest list length
    if (listA[i] in listB) and (listA[i] in listC):
        common = True
    else:
        common = False
```

If possible, could you give an answer where it can be applied to numerous lists rather than be limited to three

Comment: Use `#` for comments in Python... And you are missing a colon at the end of the for loop

Comment: Sets are better suited to this than lists. Sets provide methods like `issubset` (`<=`) and `intersection` (`&`).

Comment: Show us some example data that you will want to process

Comment: @DavidG yeh sorry used comments in a different language

Comment: @Gerhard I have 3 string inputs from the user which is broken into separate chars via converting it to a list. It then checks for characters that are in all three. E.G  john, jake, james  would find j and return true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get all common elements of all 3 lists using set intersection:

```
intersection = set(listA) & set(listB) & set(listC)
common = bool(intersection)  # True if not empty
```

A contains-checks on two lists in a loop has time complexity `O(A*(B+C))` (quadratic). This is `O(A+B+C)` (linear).

If the entire intersection is more info than you need, you can still do the following and benefit from an early break:

```
setBC = set(listB) & set(listC)
common = any(x in setBC for x in listA)
```